# Datatable cannot refresh itself when request come

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable coming inside the popup.When I tried to change the presented value inside the datatable with ajax request , datatable values dont change . I can see the retrieved datas are correct , but these datas are not showing the datatable.

Here is the codes:

```
<script>
function CreateChart() {
    var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("piechartdiv", {
        "type": "pie",
        "theme": "light",
        "fontFamily":"Calibri",


        "dataProvider": [{
            "product":"Following",
            "value": @following,
            "color": "#009688"
        }, {
            "product":"Not following",
            "value": @notFollowing,
            "color": "#555555"

        }],
        "legend": {
            "align" : "right",
            "fontSize" : 14
        },
        "marginLeft":-100,
        "marginTop":-45,
        "marginBottom":0,
        "labelsEnabled":false,
        "colorField": "color",
        "valueField": "value",
        "titleField": "product",
        "outlineAlpha": 0.4,
        "depth3D": 15,
        "balloonText": "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>",
        "angle": 20,
        "export": {
            "enabled": true
        }
    });

    jQuery('.chart-input').off().on('input change', function () {
        var property = jQuery(this).data('property');
        var target = chart;
        var value = Number(this.value);
        chart.startDuration = 0;

        if (property == 'innerRadius') {
            value += "%";
        }

        target[property] = value;
        chart.validateNow();  
    });
    chart.addListener("clickSlice", function (event) {
        if ( event.dataItem.title == 'Unfollowing')
        {
            document.getElementById("s_open").click();
        }
    }); 
}
var isAjax = @isAjax;
if(isAjax)
{

    CreateChart();

}
else
{
    AmCharts.ready(function () {
        CreateChart();
    });
}
```

```
<button id="s_open" class="s_open btn-default" style="display:none;">Open popup</button>

<div id="testfollowing" style="display:none;">
<div class="row" style="border-radius:5px; padding:20px; background-color:#fff;">
    <table id="following" class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Following</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @Html.Raw(comparedDataTable.ToString())
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="btn s_close btn-danger">Close</button>
</div>
```

Here is the pop up with table code part :

```
var isAjax = @isAjax;
if(isAjax)
{ 

    dataTables.taskList = $('#following').dataTable({
        // the same initialization params used but left out here for brevity
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5'
        ],
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bRetrieve": true,
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Initialize the plugin
        $('#').popup({
            color: 'black',
            opacity: 0.5,
            transition: '0.3s',
            scrolllock: true
        });
    });


}
else
{
    $(new function () {
        $('#following').DataTable( {  
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'excelHtml5',
                'csvHtml5'
            ],

        } );
    });        
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Initialize the plugin
        $('#testfollowing').popup({
            color: 'black',
            opacity: 0.5,
            transition: '0.3s',
            scrolllock: true
        });
    });
}
```

Datas are given via Razor not Ajax , just the request with Ajax. How can I solve this regeneration problem?

Comment: You open the popup before waiting for the data to be loaded, try replacing `$(document).ready(function(){` with `$('#following').on('xhr.dt', function (){` to show popup when data is received.